# Instance method not found - for App Delegate property

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, warnings, appdelegate

OK, here's my situation...

**My App Delegate is declared as follows :**

```
@interface AppDelegate : NSObject <NSApplicationDelegate>

@property (assign) IBOutlet NSWindow *window;
@property (assign) ppDocumentManager* documentManager;
```

**Now, from a different location I'm trying to access `documentManager`, like this :**

```
AppDelegate* de = (AppDelegate*)[[NSApplication sharedApplication] delegate]; 
ppDocumentManager* docs = [de documentManager];
```

And, at the top of the file, I've also added `@class AppDelegate;` so that the compiler knows what `AppDelegate` stands for.

**And it works fine.**

---

**However**, I keep getting warnings :

```
Instance method '-documentManager' not found (return type defaults to 'id')
```

What should I do in order to eliminate all the warnings?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, this is what worked for me :

- I had decided to use `@class AppDelegate;` at the beginning of the `.m` file making use of `documentManager`, in order to avoid the risk of circular references.

However, it turns out that wasn't necessary.

I just imported `AppDelegate.h` and everything comes into place.

Pheww....

Comment: You won't import .m files, so no risk of circular import. Plus, @class tells the compiler nothing about methods and properties of that class.

Comment: @FirozeLafeer That's true. :-)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and I found out it came from having the appdelegate named "AppDelegate" and not some custom name like "MyAppDelegate".

Rename my class to "MyAppDelegate" and the import to "MyAppDelegate.h" made the trick.